# removing jquery elastic from a textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea

I am using jquery elastic to automatically resize the height of a text area as the content grows.

my text area has id #statusupdate

and so to apply elastic to it all I have to do is this

```
$('#statusupdate').elastic();
```

Pretty simple!

My script detects the user clicking outside of the text area and if this happens removes the user's text and adds a class to the text area to make it less prominent on the screen.

The problem is that with elastic applied to the text area the height of the text area seems to be set by elastic and I cant re set it. Is there any way that I can remove elastic from my text area or reset it's data?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I tried looking through the elastic code (http://unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/ for those playing at home). Perhaps, you could try adding $twin.addClass('cloneClass'); in the plugin and then style based .cloneClass.   What I don't understand is that, based on the demo page, updating the elastic one doesn't seem to update the original textarea.

Comment: I'm afraid that You have to rewrite the plugin to do that

Comment: If you are still having issues for whatever reason, please create a jsfiddle or upload some css and other jquery you are running so we can take a look. If at all possible please elaborate on why none of the answers I provided seem to work for you =)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti Is that a fact that you have to rewrite this plugin to do that?? I don't see why using a !important in the CSS as a worst case option wouldn't solve the problem. Or by changing the class used when the user selects off the textarea to shrink the height? Thanks for your input

Comment: @ityler22 maybe your solution is acceptable, but i don't think it's the correct way, which would be the implement a `$('yourSelector').elastic("destroy");` method in the plugin that cleans up what have been added. At least IMHO!

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an elegant way to unbind/rebind elastic's events, but for a quick brute-force override you can use the !important attribute to override the CSS on the textarea's height.

Create a textarea with a rows attribute (so we know what size to revert the textarea to):

```
<textarea rows="4"></textarea>
```

Attach focus/blur functions to the textarea to override/reset the height:

```
jQuery(function() {
   $('textarea').focus(function() {
    // remove any height overrides
    $(this).css('height', '');
    // make it elastic
    $('textarea').elastic();
   });
     $('textarea').blur(function() {
     // override the height on the textarea to force it back to its original height
     $(this).css('height', $(this).attr("rows") + 'em !important'); 
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the copy and paste but I saw this elsewhere and it doesn't work nicely for me. For now I am removing the entire textarea and then recreating it without elastic attached which is doing the job

Comment: Ok just trying to help, If you say it's not working without why it's not working how else can we help you?? At worst case you should be able to use the brute-force override by adding !important to the css class on the textarea. Alone, I would think this resolves your issue.

Comment: Sorry, it just seems that even when I add !important the css still doesn't overide what elastic is setting the height to. I will play around with it a bit more but at the moment removing the entire element and then putting in a duplicate without elastic seems to be doing the trick. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried the method @Nicola suggested above to use: `$('yourSelector').elastic("destroy");`

Answer (score 0):

Using the wysihtml5 editor I have found that simply setting the textarea height to auto seems to override elastic:

```
$('textarea').css('height', 'auto');
```

Elastic can then be re-initialised later if needed:

```
$('textarea').elastic();
```

I need to do some more testing, but I've not noticed any issues so far (using elastic 1.6.11).